# read file in a specific region line by line in file

Tags: c, file

I have a text file where every row has the format

A  B:C

I want to read it using C language, but all i want to get in every line is what comes after the ':'. In other words I want to get only the C value in every line of the file, but all I want to do is read the file line-by-line and get every row's values.

Any idea to do that?

Comment: Read each line using, for example, `fgets`, then examine each string using `strtok`. You can find these using `man fgets` and `man strok`.

Comment: Show what you have tried, and show what got you stumped.

Answer (score 4):

open the file for reading

```
fp = fopen("file.txt" , "r");
```

Use fgets() to read the line

```
 fgets (str, MAX_LENGTH, fp);
```

Use Strtok to break according to ":"

```
ptr = strtok(str,":");
```

Answer (score 1):

Read  file line by line by using [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)

`fgets(line,MAX_SIZE,file_stream);`

And use [`strchr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr), to get the position from where C starts

```
char *ptr=strchr(line,':'); //ptr points to the : location 

//now if you Move ptr location next to ':' ptr points to C 

printf("C=%s",ptr+1);
```

And with out using additional pointer, You can do like this

```
printf("C=%s",strchr(line,':')+1);
```

Repeat these  steps until reaching end of file. By checking the return value of `fgets()` against `NULL`.

Note: In this A B:C , if A or B consists : then You need to Apply logic accordingly.
You can also use [`strrchr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strrchr)